# Make a label both Italic and Bold style in Matplotlib with stix font

Tags: matplotlib

I am trying to generate a plot with matplotlib and I use the 'stix' font (rcParams['mathtext.fontset'] = 'stix') in order to have smooth font size transitions from text to math text. However, some of my math symbols I want to be Italic (scalar values) and some to be Italic **AND** Bold (tensors). I do not want to go through the solution of using Latex rendering cause then other things are messed up.

I will give you a small example that depicts the problem:

```
from numpy import *
from matplotlib.pyplot import * 

# Chaning font to stix
rcParams['mathtext.fontset'] = 'stix'

# Some data to constract this plotting example
datax=[0,1,2]
datay=[8,9,10]
datay2=[8,15,10]

fig, ay = subplots()

ay.plot(datax, datay, color="0.", ls='-', label= r"$F_{\alpha}$")
ay.plot(datax, datay2, color="0.", ls='-', label=r"$\mathbf{F_{\alpha}}$")

# Now add the legend with some customizations.
legend = ay.legend(loc='left', shadow=True)

#frame = legend.get_frame()
#frame.set_facecolor('0.90')
xlabel(r"x label",fontsize=18)
ylabel(r'y label', fontsize=18)
grid()

show()
```

If you run the code the first label is Italic and the second label is Bold. How could I achieve the second label to be Bold AND Italic?

[Problem with math text to be Italic and bold](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMqcq.png)

Comment: I don't think it's possible. You may need to use true latex (i.e. usetex=True) and then this question might help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14395/bold-italic-vectors

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A few more specific `mathtext` params are needed:

```
from numpy import *
from matplotlib.pyplot import *

# Changing font to stix; setting specialized math font properties as directly as possible
rcParams['mathtext.fontset'] = 'custom'
rcParams['mathtext.it'] = 'STIXGeneral:italic'
rcParams['mathtext.bf'] = 'STIXGeneral:italic:bold'

# Some data to construct this plotting example
datax=[0,1,2]
datay=[8,9,10]
datay2=[8,15,10]

fig, ay = subplots()

ay.plot(datax, datay, color="0.", ls='-', label= r"$\mathit{F_{\alpha}}$")
ay.plot(datax, datay2, color="0.", ls='-', label=r"$\mathbf{F_{\alpha}}$")

# Now add the legend with some customizations.
legend = ay.legend(loc='left', shadow=True)

# Using the specialized math font again
xlabel(r"$\mathbf{x}$ label",fontsize=18)
ylabel(r'y label', fontsize=18)
grid()

show()
```

[image]

Note that I used the `mathbf` in an axis label, too. Would probably change the rest of the label to a STIX font, which you can define a non-italic-non-bold case of: see the [docs](http://matplotlib.org/users/mathtext.html?highlight=math%20font) under 'Custom fonts'.

There are also at least two examples in the matplotlib Gallery that might help: [one looking at font families](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/mathtext_fontfamily_example.html#sphx-glr-gallery-text-labels-and-annotations-mathtext-fontfamily-example-py) and [another reminding us which STIX fonts are which](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/stix_fonts_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-text-labels-and-annotations-stix-fonts-demo-py).

Comment: This is so great! 1000 upvotes. I've read the documentation on the `mathtext` rcParams, but couldn't figure out the syntax for specifying the particular stix font varants. Thanks so much.

Comment: :) I couldn't get there from the docs either, I think I had to read some source. However there are now two official examples and a new rcParam -- added at the end of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As of [matplotlib version 3.8](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/prev_whats_new/whats_new_3.8.0.html#bold-italic-mathtext-command-mathbfit) there is the `\mathbfit` command:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams['font.family'] = 'serif'
plt.rcParams['font.serif'] = 'Nimbus Roman'
plt.rcParams['mathtext.fontset'] = 'stix'

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([], label= r"italic (default): $F_\alpha$")
ax.plot([], label=r"roman: $\mathrm{F_\alpha}$")
ax.plot([], label=r"bold: $\mathbf{F_\alpha}$")
ax.plot([], label=r"bold and italic: $\mathbfit{F_\alpha}$")
ax.legend(fontsize='xx-large')
```

[image: bold and italic math text]

Answer (score -3):

So MatplotLib is using LaTeX syntax, so my best guess is that you can use LaTeX syntax for how to get italicized and bold, which is

```
 \textbf{\textit{text}}
```

So in your case it would be

```
ay.plot(datax, datay2, color="0.", ls='-', label= r"$\mathbf{ \textit{F_{\alpha}} }$")
```