# Bold Format Suptitle with Mathematical Expression

Tags: python, matplotlib, title, suptitle

This line of code:

```
plt.suptitle("Observed and Predicted $U_{dec,c}$",x=mid,fontweight='bold')
```

Produces a suptitle like this:

[image]

However, I require the entire string to be in bold, including the mathematical expression, and for various reasons I need to use plt.suptitle, not plt.title. I would be grateful for any advice on how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\mathbf`:

```
from numpy import *
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

rcParams['mathtext.fontset'] = 'custom'
rcParams['mathtext.it'] = 'STIXGeneral:italic'
rcParams['mathtext.bf'] = 'STIXGeneral:italic:bold'

plt.suptitle(r"Observed and Predicted $\mathbf{U_{dec,c}}$", fontweight='bold')
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Credits (for italic): https://stackoverflow.com/a/44790518

Here is a list of [Latex symbols](https://mirror.kku.ac.th/CTAN/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf).

For more questions, you can checkout [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/595/how-can-i-get-bold-math-symbols).

Comment: Thank you; that's very helpful. But how do I keep the mathematical expression italicised, as in the image I uploaded?

Comment: @chrisprt I have edited my answer. You can check it out now! If you find the answer helpful then you can accept it.:)

Answer (score 1):

There are many options, a simple one is to use `\mathbf`:

```
plt.suptitle(r"Observed and Predicted $\mathbf{U_{dec,c}}$", fontweight='bold')
```

[image: mathbf]

You can find more options [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/595/how-can-i-get-bold-math-symbols).

Comment: Thank you; that's very helpful. But how do I keep the mathematical expression italicised, as in the image I uploaded?